# mathtools: tagging with words and a number in align

Tags: numbering, align, mathtools

How does one tag an equation with both words and numbers?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newenvironment{Dequation}
{%                                                                                  
  \def\tagform@##1{%                                                                
    \maketag@@@{\makebox[0pt][r]{(\ignorespaces##1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}}%         
  \ignorespaces                                                                     
}
{%                                                                                  
  \def\tagform@##1{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces##1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}%            
  \ignorespacesafterend                                                             
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{Dequation}
\begin{align*}
3 &= 3\\
4 &= 4\\
6 &= 6\tag{since $x_0 = 0$}\label{six}
\end{align*}
\end{Dequation}
\end{document}
```

So I want to reference my equation, but I want the reference to be `equation (1)`.  Therefore, it would seem strange if the equation wasn't numbered if someone was looking for that reference.

Comment: Should you use the regular `align` environment instead of the `*` version? Then you would write in your document `... Equation \ref{six}...` I think that's what you're asking. If not, can you make the question more clear?

Comment: @darthbith if I specify a named tag, I won't have a number tag.  I need both a name and a number (for refence) that doesn't look awkward.

Comment: In written form, authors should not do this. It is considered bad style. Either write it in the text, or use the method described by Andrew.

Comment: @dustin Hmm thanks for clarifying. Guess I misunderstand your intent!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be abusing `\tag` to set side comments.  Just use an alignment to place them:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
3 &= 3&\qquad& \notag\\
4 &= 4&&\text{(since \( p \) is prime)} \notag\\
6 &= 6&&\text{(since \( x_0 = 0 \))}\label{six}
\end{alignat}

By equation~\eqref{six}\dots

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one, rather hackish, way to obtain this dual numbering/tagging label:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\newenvironment{Dequation}
{%                                                                                  
  \def\tagform@##1{%                                                                
    \maketag@@@{\makebox[0pt][r]{(\ignorespaces##1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}}%         
  \ignorespaces                                                                     
}
{%                                                                                  
  \def\tagform@##1{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces##1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}%            
  \ignorespacesafterend                                                             
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\refstepcounter{equation}\label{six}
\begin{Dequation}
\begin{align*}
3 &= 3\\
4 &= 4\\
6 &= 6\tag{since $x_0 = 0$\upshape{)\,(}\ref{six}}
\end{align*}
\end{Dequation}
See~\eqref{six}.
\end{document}
```

It's an easy way out, yet definitely viable means, to obtain the output. You manually step the relevant `equation` counter outside the `Dequation` environment and label it. Then use it in reference form as part of the `\tag`. Note that [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) might not be happy with this approach.

---

A far more common approach to tagging and labelling is by setting the `\tag` as a descriptor (and thus part of the equation). Here's a way that doesn't affect the horizontal alignment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\newenvironment{Dequation}
{%                                                                                  
  \def\tagform@##1{%                                                                
    \maketag@@@{\makebox[0pt][r]{(\ignorespaces##1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}}%         
  \ignorespaces                                                                     
}
{%                                                                                  
  \def\tagform@##1{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces##1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}%            
  \ignorespacesafterend                                                             
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\eqcomment}[1]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\quad\upshape(#1)}}
\begin{document}

\begin{Dequation}
\begin{align}
3 &= 3 \nonumber \\
4 &= 4 \nonumber \\
6 &= 6 \eqcomment{since $x_0 = 0$}\label{six}
\end{align}
\end{Dequation}
See~\eqref{six}.
\end{document}
```