# Add equation name underneath equation number

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath

I am wondering if it is possible (and if so how) to add names to equations just underneath the equation number. I am just using the standard `equation` environment to display the equation centered in the middle of the page, with the equation number flushed to the right hand side. I need to put some text immediately below the equation number to serve as the equation's name. Other requirements include:

- The text should be horizontally right-aligned with the equation number and should not affect the latter's vertical alignment with the equation; i.e. the equation and equation number should still be vertically in line with each other.
- The vertical spacing between the equation number and name should be standard text spacing; i.e. if the equation is vertically tall, there should not be excess space between the equation number and name.
- The text should be able to be formatted in different font styles. Right now, I need to format it in `\sf`.

Here is a MWE (without the equation name):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
\label{sec:section1}
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:label}
    \boxed{M\approx\frac{\pi}{4}\left(\frac{2d}{\lambda_o}\right)^2\left(\mathrm{NA}\right)^2}
\end{equation}

Reference \eqref{eqn:label}.

\end{document}
```

Here is a snapshot example of what I'd like to achieve (taken from Saleh, 2007):
[image: Equation with name under number]

I have tried using the `\tag` command, but realized that this not only replaces the equation number, which I do not want, but also causes the equation number counter to skip that particular equation. Ideally, the equation should still function as a regular numbered equation, that can be number-referenced (via `\eqref` or other), but with the addition of some text below the equation number.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: does this text *have* to be entered as part of the displayed equation?  would you be willing to consider a separate line, flushed right, immediately following the numbered display?

Comment: @barbara, Thanks for the welcome. I have added a picture example that should make it clearer. The text should be on the next line of the equation number, but still within the general "space" of the equation. I suppose then that it should be part of the equation.

Comment: Related [mathtools: tagging with words and a number in align](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127954/15717)

Answer (score 21):

Here's an easy by using the starred version of `\tag` from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcommand{\eqname}[1]{\tag*{#1}}% Tag equation with name
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  f(x) &= a \\ \eqname{Constant} \\
  g(x) &= ax \\ \eqname{Linear} \\
  h(x) &= ax^2+bx+c \label{abc} \\ \eqname{Quadratic}
\end{align}
See~\eqref{abc}.
\end{document}
```

For [consistency](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764), I've wrapped `\tag*` inside `\eqname`.

---

Depending on your equation construction, you can adjust the vertical skip between the equation and the name:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcommand{\eqname}[1]{\tag*{#1}}% Tag equation with name
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \boxed{M \approx \frac{\pi}{4}\biggr(\frac{2d}{\lambda_0}\biggr)^2(\text{NA})^2} \label{abc} \\[-\baselineskip]
  \eqname{Number of TE Modes}
\end{align}
See~\eqref{abc}.
\end{document}
```

Here I've moved it up by `\baselineskip`, but you can adjust this to your liking.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Admittedly, it is a very clean solution. However, because of the line break, the space between the equation number and equation name will get large if the equation is tall. Sorry I did not mention this requirement earlier, but it has since been edited into my original question. As can be seen in the image example I added, the equation name should take its "next line" reference from the equation number and not the equation itself. Also, it does not seem to work with the `equation` environment, in which case, only the `eqname` is shown without the equation number.

Comment: @NicholasWong: See the update at the end of my answer.

Comment: @Werner Thank you for your solution, I have begun to integrate it into my thesis as it comes rather handy being able to name equations here and there. I have noticed however that if the `eqname` or `tag*{}` is too long then it offsets the equation from a centre alignment. Do you have any ways to deal with this? Thank you

Comment: @Fiztban: In that case it may be more suitable to use the following definition: `\newcommand{\eqname}[1]{\tag*{\llap{#1}}}`

Answer (score 9):

The following example hacks into the internals of package `amsmath` to add the equation name at the stage, where the equation tag is set in the displayed equation.

- `\eqname{<name of the equation>}` sets the equation name. The name increases the depth of the equation tag, thus the base line of the equation number does not change.
- The width of the equation name decreases the space that is available for the equation. Thus the equation number might be moved down (feature of `amsmath`) as shown in equation 5 of the example.

  The star form `\eqname*` ignores the width of the equation name. It can be used, if it is clear, that the equation name does not collide with the contents of the equation, see equation 6 of the example.
- Package `nameref` is supported to reference the name of the equation. The label name is given in the optional argument. (The example uses package `nameref`, but the package is not required.)
- The formatting of the equation name can be changed by redefining `\eqnameref`. The example uses `\textsf` as requested in the [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128050/add-equation-name-underneath-equation-number#comment288264_128057).

Example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nameref}

\newcommand*{\eqnameformat}[1]{%
  \textsf{#1}%
}

\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable{\org@maketag@@@}{%
  \let\org@maketag@@@\maketag@@@
  \renewcommand*{\maketag@@@}[1]{%
    \org@maketag@@@{%
      \@ifundefined{eq@name}{#1}{%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r@{}}%
          #1\tabularnewline
          \eqnameformat{\@nameuse{eq@name}}%
        \end{tabular}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\newif\ifeqname@star
\newcommand*{\eqname}{%
  \@ifstar{\eqname@startrue\eqname@}{\eqname@starfalse\eqname@}%
}
\newcommand*{\eqname@}[2][]{%
  \gdef\eq@name{#1}%
  \ifx\eq@name\@empty
  \else
    \begingroup
      \@ifundefined{GetTitleString}{%
        \gdef\@currenteqlabelname{#2}%
      }{%
        \GetTitleString{#2}%
        \global\let\@currenteqlabelname\GetTitleStringResult
      }%
      \let\@currentlabelname\@currenteqlabelname
      \label{#1}%
    \endgroup
  \fi
  %
  \gdef\eq@name{#2}%
  \ifx\eq@name\@empty
    \global\let\eq@name\relax
  \else
    \ifeqname@star
      \gdef\eq@name{\llap{#2}}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\@ifdefinable{\org@make@display@tag}{%
  \let\org@make@display@tag\make@display@tag
  \def\make@display@tag{%
    \@ifundefined{@currenteqlabelname}{}{%
      \let\@currentlabelname\@currenteqlabelname
    }%
    \org@make@display@tag
  }%
}
\let\eq@name\relax
\let\@currenteqlabelname\relax
\g@addto@macro\displ@y@{%
  \global\let\eq@name\relax
  \global\let\@currenteqlabelname\relax
}
\@ifdefinable{\org@math@cr@@}{%
  \let\org@math@cr@@\math@cr@@
  \def\math@cr@@[#1]{%
    \org@math@cr@@[{#1}]%
    \noalign{%
      \global\let\eq@name\relax
    }%
  }%
}
\@ifdefinable{\org@eqref}{%
  \let\org@eqref\eqref
  \renewcommand*{\eqref}[1]{%
    \begingroup
      \let\eq@name\relax
      \org@eqref{#1}%
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\g@addto@macro\equation{%
  \eqname{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% some test cases

The first equation \eqref{eq:einstein} with  name ``\nameref{eq:einstein}'',
the second equation \eqref{eq:second} and
and the last equation \eqref{eq:last}  with name ``\nameref{eq:last}''.

\begin{gather}
\eqname[eq:einstein]{Einstein}
E=mc^2\\
\label{eq:second}
a=b
\end{gather}

\begin{equation}
\eqname{Name AB}
a=b
\end{equation}

\begin{gather}
x=y
\end{gather}

\begin{gather}
\eqname{A longer equation name A/no star}
a=b=c=d=e=f=g=h=i=j\\
\eqname*[eq:last]{A longer equation name B/star}
a=b=c=d=e=f=g=h=i=j
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: This is a good solution, thank you. However, it seems that the `\eqref` referencing only works well with the `gather` environment, whereas if I use it for an equation from an `equation` environment, the `eqname` gets displayed below the equation number, similar to the problems mentioned in the comments to the previous solutions.

Comment: @NicholasWong: I can reproduce it, if `\eqref` is used *inside* an equation. Thus I have updated the answer to fix this issue for `\eqref`.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. There is another issue however. I tried the `align` environment with multiple equation lines and it works with your code. Now I want to box all the equations, have each equation numbered, and place the `eqname` underneath the last equation number. I tried out the `empheq` package and its `\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align}`...`\end{empheq}` suggestion. Everything compiles well, but in the output, the equation numbers are not quite vertically aligned to their respective equations. The alignment is fine without the `eqname` at the end.

Comment: By the way, I just noticed that if I use `\eqname` in an `equation` environment, and then have a subsequent `equation` without `\eqname` but just the usual `\label`, then the equation name of the first `equation` gets displayed underneath the second equation's number as well.

Comment: @NicholasWong: Unnamed equation fixed.

Comment: @NicholasWong: Issue of package `empheq`: This is something that should be fixed there.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a solution.  I introduce the environment `Nequation` to mean "named equation," in which the name is passed as an argument.  I show how it does not screw up the use of `equation` environment's numbering scheme.  [EDITED to fix referencing by label, and to add sections to eq #, and also to allow text formatting to name, per user request]

In response to the user's latest query, sub and sub-sub sections can be added where I first `\renewcommand\theequation{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}`.  Text formatting can come in one of two ways.  It can be made to happen for every label, as I have done with `\small` in the `Nequation` environment, or it can be done on a label-by-label basis, as I show with `\textsf` in the actual invocation line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\stackalignment{r}
\def\useanchorwidth{T}
\def\stacktype{L}
\newlength\eqshift
\setlength\eqshift{\widthof{)}}
\renewcommand\theequation{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
\let\savetheequation\theequation
\newenvironment{Nequation}[1]{%
  \def\thecurrentname{#1}%
  \let\theequation\savetheequation%
  \begin{equation}%
  \renewcommand\theequation{%
    \stackunder{\savetheequation}%
    {{\small\thecurrentname}\hspace{-\the\eqshift}}}%
}{%
  \end{equation}%
  \let\theequation\savetheequation%
  \ignorespacesafterend%
}
\begin{document}
\section{New Section}
\begin{Nequation}{\textsf{Equation Name}}
  \label{eqn:label}
    y=mx+c
\end{Nequation}
We find in equation~\eqref{eqn:label}, a different result than
\begin{equation}
    \label{eqtwo}
    y=mx^2+c
\end{equation}
However, in equation~\eqref{eqtwo}\ldots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Yes this is what I was after. However, there are some problems. Firstly, the equation name gets displayed together with the number when I reference the equation using \eqref. I need just the equation number to be displayed as how we usually reference equations. Secondly, while the equation counter is correct, it does not display the section/subsection enumeration, and trying \numberwithin{Nequation}{section} did not work.

Comment: @NicholasWong I'll give some thought to the label issue.  However, it would help if you, in your question, posted a complete MWE (minimum working example), since it is likely you are not using the `article` class if you have things like section/subsection enumeration.  We can't know such things unless you tell us in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I am still new to this. Thanks for the edit. Actually for the section enumeration problem, I tried running your MWE with the `article` class. I just added the `amsmath` package and used the `\numberwithin` command, but only the equation from the regular `equation` environment has its number displayed with the section numbering.

Comment: It looks quite good now, though is there any way to make this scalable to `subsection`, `subsubsection`, etc.? I am trying (rather slowly) to understand your code, and I am guessing it has something to do with the `\thesection` command. Also, and I really apologize for not making this clear earlier, it would be good if I can format the text within the `Equation Name` field. Right now, I am using `\sf` formatting, but I hope to be able to do other formatting in future use. Currently, adding any formatting produces an "Undefined control sequence" error.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thank you for the updates.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek No problem