# amsmath left- and right aligned Formulas in one line

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath

I thought this would be a common problem, but I can't find any satisfying answer to this.
I am using the `amsmath` package. Using the `align` environment is helpful for separating the two expressions, but they are still left-aligned. However, I'd prefer having the contents of the bracket aligned on the right, next to the formula number.
Example in the picture below :

[image: template Formula]

Comment: Does this work for you? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173970/add-equation-name-besides-equation-number-so-that-eqref-inserts-only-the-numbe

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself

```
\begin{flalign}
            &\sum\limits_{m=1}^{M_j}\sum\limits_{t=0}^{T} x_{jmt}=1 &(j=0,\dots,J+1)
    \end{flalign}
```

This does the trick.