# Insert name underneath equation

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I have this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    dy_{t}
        =\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(x_{t},t)dt
        +\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x_{t},t)dx_{t}
        +\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}(x_{t},t)(dx_{t})^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

which produces this output

[image]

Is there a way to give the equation a name, f.x. *Itô's Lemma*, and insert it directly underneath the equation (centered)? The idea is that it is still a part of the `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` environment. I have read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128050/add-equation-name-underneath-equation-number), but the solution is not exactly the same. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem like a good idea, but the document is yours. The approach in the linked question is much worse, however.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
    dy_{t}
        =\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(x_{t},t)dt
        +\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x_{t},t)dx_{t}
        +\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}(x_{t},t)(dx_{t})^2
\\
\text{Itô's lemma}\notag
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For completeness, I'd rather go with something like below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

We obtain the following equation, known as \emph{Itô's lemma},
\begin{equation}
    dy_{t}
        =\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(x_{t},t)dt
        +\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x_{t},t)dx_{t}
        +\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}(x_{t},t)(dx_{t})^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the case you seem to be after, I can suggest something like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

\section{Main body}

We recall the fundamental \emph{Pythagoras' theorem}
\begin{equation}\label{pyth}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}
From it we easily obtain the following equation, known as \emph{Itô's lemma},
\begin{equation}\label{ito}
    dy_{t}
        =\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(x_{t},t)dt
        +\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x_{t},t)dx_{t}
        +\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}(x_{t},t)(dx_{t})^2
\end{equation}

\begin{fleqn}[2em]
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\section{Equations}

Pythagoras' theorem
\begin{equation}\tag{\ref{pyth}}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}

Itô's lemma
\begin{equation}\tag{\ref{ito}}
    dy_{t}
        =\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(x_{t},t)dt
        +\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x_{t},t)dx_{t}
        +\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}(x_{t},t)(dx_{t})^2
\end{equation}

\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, with the references next to the name:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

\section{Main body}

We recall the fundamental \emph{Pythagoras' theorem}
\begin{equation}\label{pyth}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}
From it we easily obtain the following equation, known as \emph{Itô's lemma},
\begin{equation}\label{ito}
    dy_{t}
        =\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(x_{t},t)dt
        +\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x_{t},t)dx_{t}
        +\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}(x_{t},t)(dx_{t})^2
\end{equation}

\begin{fleqn}[2em]
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\section{Equations}

Pythagoras' theorem~\eqref{pyth}
\begin{equation*}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation*}

Itô's lemma~\eqref{ito}
\begin{equation*}
    dy_{t}
        =\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(x_{t},t)dt
        +\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x_{t},t)dx_{t}
        +\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}(x_{t},t)(dx_{t})^2
\end{equation*}

\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like the second option. If you have to insert a final mark because it's end of paragraph, would you use `)^2`**`\ .`**`\end{equation}`?

Comment: @manooooh I usually add punctuation directly, without spaces.

Comment: @egreg Thank you! The reason I asked the question is that I am writing a document, where I at the end of it list/recall all the equations from the document. This means that I have 1-2 pages consisting only of equations. Since some of them are quite similar, it helps if they're named. If we're talking about writing an article, then I completely agree that your second solution is better.

Comment: @Andreas In that case I'd go with the name and the equation on the next line, using (almost) flush left equations (you can mix standard centered equations and flush left in the same document with the `nccmath` package); a quad or two from the margin for the equation would be OK.

Comment: @egreg I'll look into that package, thank you.

Comment: @Andreas I added a couple of suggestions

Comment: @egreg Oh, great. I really like the layout of the new suggestions! However, it seems that in those suggestions, you're manually re-typing the equations. Two days ago I received help on how to automatically recall all equations [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450515/automatically-list-all-equations-from-document] . I don't know if that is compatible with your solution, but I'll look into it, since your suggestions look much cleaner than what I had in mind.